# Can I use a character constant in a macro without single quotes to produce a constant?

Tags: c, gcc, macros

I have a macro that I stupidly set up when developing under AIX.  It generates a 'trigger' value that I use in case switches.  Like so:

```
#define TRIGGER_BUTTON(c) ((WIDGET_BUTTON << 16) | 'c')
```

meant to be used in a case switch, like so:

```
switch(GetTrigger()) {
case TRIGGER_BUTTON(A):    /* This constant sent by button A */
    break;
}
```

The AIX xlc compiler handled this fine, but gcc doesn't.  Turns out it's not legal C, but I have tons of code that uses this macro.  I could run a bulk sed script and change all that code to use a new macro that requires you to code it with the trigger character quoted, but I found a post here that seemed to suggest a portable solution.

```
#define TRIGGER_BUTTON(c) ((WIDGET_BUTTON << 16) | ##c[0])
```

This works, in the sense that both the AIX compiler and gcc accept it.  But the problem is that the resulting expansion is not a valid integer constant, and so can't be used in a case switch.  I guess it's producing code that actually puts together the combined integer value at run time from a constant string created from the macro argument - rather than producing a constant integer at compile time.

```
printf("%x\n", TRIGGER_BUTTON(A));
```

correctly prints  30041  (where WIDGET_BUTTON is defined as 3)

but the compiler spits out the case TRIGGER_BUTTON(A) as an invalid integer expression.

So, back to the drawing board - or my sed script, if I have to.  Can anybody think of a way to stringize a non-quoted character and turn it into an integer constant?

Didn't think so... ;-)

But thanks anyway.

Comment: It's not very likely that you switched from AIX to Windows, but Microsoft offers the ["charizing operator"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91tt6dfs.aspx) `#@` in analogy to the stringizing operator `#` as an extension.

Comment: `#define TRIGGER_BUTTON(c) ((3 << 16) | (""#c [0]))` should work.

Comment: @alk yes: http://ideone.com/Gseu9A

Comment: @mch: The OP says that it works, but the macro is used as a `switch` case constant, and it won't work there, because it's not an integer constant.

Comment: In your possible work around, you have `##`, which is the token pasting operator. I think you meant `#`, which is the quoting operator.

Comment: @MOehm something like that: http://ideone.com/2ME6f1 ?

Comment: @mch: No, something like that: `switch (var) { case MACRO(A): ...}`